# C# eBay Listing Recommendation API

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, streamreader, ebay-api

I'm having trouble getting any type of response from the Listing Recommendation API.  I keep getting a generic 500 message on my return.  I've set up my headers the way they recommend here: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/listing-recommendation/Concepts/MakingACall.html

I've tried using the information from the documentation on the call here: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/listing-recommendation/CallRef/itemRecommendations.html#Samples

But every variation of my code comes up bad.  Below is a sample of the code.  I've tried it with and without the commented out line of code with the same results.  It always fails on the line response.GetResponseStream.  Thanks for your help.

```
public static void test(string AuthToken, string listing, log4net.ILog log)
    {
        string url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/selling/listingrecommendation/v1/item/" + listing + "/itemRecommendations/?recommendationType=ItemSpecifics";


        var listingRecommendationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        listingRecommendationRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "TOKEN " + AuthToken);
        listingRecommendationRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        listingRecommendationRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        listingRecommendationRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");
        listingRecommendationRequest.Method = "GET";

        //listingRecommendationRequest.Headers.Add("recommendationType", "ItemSpecifics");

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)listingRecommendationRequest.GetResponse();

        string result;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(result));

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                // Read Json values here
                var pt = reader.Path;
                var val = reader.Value.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Adding image of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to get the item specifics recommendations that are suggested by eBay when manually editing a listing.  These suggestions change based on what is in your title.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's not working right now. I'm also getting a 500 response, even from the basic /latestVersion call.

Comment: A day later with still the same 500 response. I think something has to be wrong with the code.

Comment: *shrug* I'm making the request through Postman with a token I know to be valid (and I get an "invalid token" response when I omit it) so I don't think it's your code.

Comment: I'm guessing this API doesn't get a lot attention. It's [being deprecated](https://go.developer.ebay.com/api-documentation) ("Work is underway to replace the Listing Recommendation API. We recommend you integrate with the new, updated API when it becomes available.") and [hasn't been updated in almost 3 years](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/listing-recommendation/ReleaseNotes.html). Nevertheless, I put in a support ticket and will let you know what they say.

Comment: "I was able to replicate the error on my side and checking this internally with the team if this has been deprecated or replaced. 

If you are looking for product recommendations, please take a look at Trading API  > GetSuggestedCategories - to return a list of categories with the highest number of items whose titles contain the keywords you specify. 
https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSuggestedCategories.html "

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  Perhaps I am going about this wrong.  I'm trying to get the item specifics recommendations.  When you are manually editing a listing they pop up as suggestions based on what is in the title of the listing.  I would not think that suggested categories would accomplish this task.